# How do I log to stdout or stderr from an Erlang common test suite?

Tags: erlang, common-test

I'm using common_test and just want to log values to stdout or stderr.

How????

I've tried:

- ct:comment
- ct:log
- io:format

The state of the art seems to be manually combing through html files. But I'm on a server and I don't care about anything except my log line, I only want stdout. And I never want to look at an HTML file when writing tests, so advice on how to avoid that generally would be really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [ct:print](https://erlang.org/doc/man/ct.html#print-2) or [ct:pal (print and log)](https://erlang.org/doc/man/ct.html#pal-1), I'd recommend using the later, though.

(You can always use [erlang:display](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#display-1), which is a low-level access to stdout)

Keep in mind that if you use Rebar3 with the default configuration and ct values. [ct:print](https://erlang.org/doc/man/ct.html#print-2) is only shown with `--verbose`, whereas, [ct:pal](https://erlang.org/doc/man/ct.html#pal-1) is only shown if the test fails.

Comment: You can still use `ct:print` with rebar3. Just launch common test using `rebar3 ct -v`

Comment: @VenkatakumarSrinivasan I'll add that information to the response, thanks!